# How do i know where the data is being pulled out from in an excell sheet

Tags: excel, dataframe, excel-formula

So I'm dealing with many sheets and they are all linked to each other. Is there a way where I would be able to know how they are linked to each other?
Because in some cases where I would update a specific sheet the other one is updated by itself automatically ( so I wanna know how that exactly happens and from where? )

Been dealing with this problem for too long and I would really appreciate the help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out the Inquire add-in perhaps (comes pre-installed with Excel). It can visualize workbook/worksheet/cell relationships.

Comment: Have you checked "Trace dependencies" on the forumulas tab?